# Using Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81) Dual Band adapter in “AP” mode under Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi

I am trying to setup an Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81) Dual Band adapter in "AP" mode under Linux.

I am using:

- custom-built kernel 4.16.18 on Slackware 14.2 (x86_64)
- module iwlwifi
- firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode

What is really puzzling me is that even though the "iw list" command clearly reports that "AP" mode is supported by this adapter any attempts to switch to the mode with iwconfig are rejected.

See below:

```
# lspci -v
[...SNIP...]
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 119
    Memory at 81200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

# lsmod | grep "iwlwifi"
iwlwifi               176128  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              258048  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211

# iw list
Wiphy phy0
[...SNIP...]
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
[...SNIP...]

# ifconfig wlan0 up
# ifconfig
[...SNIP...]
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.253  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 70:1c:e7:05:e3:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

# iwconfig wlan0 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
# iwconfig wlan0 mode AP
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    invalid argument "AP".
```

I understand that this particular adapter does not support "master" mode. However it does list "AP" mode as supported.

Why can't iwconfig switch the card to "AP" mode?

Any help is appreciated.